# Conplex/real Integration and poles of function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

So I am working on the following problem:

Let $\Delta $ be the unit disk centered at origin, and $f$ is holomorphic on $\Delta-\{0\}$. If $$\int_\Delta|f|dxdy<\infty$$ show that $f$ has at most a degree 1 pole at 0.

I start with writting the integral in polar coordinate: $$\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi} r|f(re^{i\theta})|d\theta dr$$
The inner integral is finite for various value of $r$. So the integral $$\int_{|z|=1}fdz\leq \int_{|z|=1}|f||dz|<\infty$$ So from here where do I go, my goal is show that $zf(z)$ is a holormophic function on $\Delta$. I thought of the function $$F(z)=\int_{|\xi|=1}\frac{\xi f(\xi)}{\xi-z}d\xi"="2\pi izf(z) $$
I put a quotation mark because I want some this equality to come out. This equality does not follow unless $F(z)$ is holormophic and finite. But how can we show that based on what we have?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you go from $|f|$ to $|f|^2$ in your post? Is one of these a typo?

Comment: I edited, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: This reminds me of the mean value property. Perhaps that is of some interest here?

Comment: See my answer i think i got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that 
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nz^n.
$$
If $a_{k}\ne 0$, for some $k>1$, then
$$
a_{-k}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\lvert z\rvert=r}z^{k-1}f(z)\,dz,
$$
and hence
$$
\lvert a_{-k}\rvert\le  r^{k}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\lvert\, f(r\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta})\rvert\,d\vartheta 
$$
and thus
$$
\frac{\lvert a_{-k}\rvert}{r^k}\le
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\lvert\, f(r\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta})\rvert\,d\vartheta.
$$
But
$$
\int_{\Delta}\lvert\,f\rvert\,dx\,dy=\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\int_0^1 \lvert f(r\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta})\rvert \,r\,dr\right)d\vartheta\ge
\int_0^{1}
\frac{\lvert a_{-k}\rvert\,dr}{r^{k-1}}=\infty,
$$
as $\int_0^1 r^{-s}\,dr=\infty$ iff $s\ge-1$

Answer (score 0):

From the previous post we know that $$|\int_{|z|=1}fdz|\leq \int_{|z|=1}|f||dz|$$ The right hand is exactly the integral $$\int_{|z|=1}|f|\cdot |z|dz=\int_0^{2\pi} r|f(re^{i\theta}|d\theta$$, where $r=1$. So $\int_{|z|=1}zf(z)$ is finite. Assume the integral is zero, if not u can subtract the constant on both side. By Morera Thorem, $zf(z)$ is holmorphic on $\Delta$.

Comment: Look, I'm no genius at complex analysis, and in light of this, maybe I'm missing something, but I thought Morera required the integral to vanish along *any* closed path, not just a circular one.  Am I in error here?

Comment: First of all thanks for your dedicated answer. Morera does require any closed path, but can we argue using homotopicity of circle to a closed path? Assume the path does not wind, if it does break the curve into pieces. I dont know if this works. If this is bogus, then my proof is false

Comment: Thanks for the kind words.  Your question is an interesting one; as far as I can see, it *might* work if you can use one of those tricks whereby you connect the circle with an arbitrary closed path in $\Delta$ by yet a third path which is traced each way during the integration process.  Is that clear without a diagram, does it make sense?  Not sure, not sure, worth thinking about!  Cheers!

Comment: @amathnerd: Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f(z)$ has a pole of order $n \ge 2$ at the origin.  Then is it not the case that

$g(z) = z^n f(z) \tag{1}$

for some $g(z) \in H(\Delta)$?  It is indeed; see [this widipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_%28complex_analysis%29). Furthermore, $g(0) \ne 0$, whence $\vert g(0) \vert > 0$.  Thus there is a real $\gamma > 0$ with $\vert g(0) \vert > \gamma$, and since $g(z)$, hence $\vert g(z) \vert: \Delta \to \Bbb R$ is continuous,  there exists real $\rho \in (0, 1)$, such that $\vert g(z) \vert > \gamma$ for $z \in \bar D (0, \rho)$, where $D(0, \rho)$ is the disk or radius $\rho$ centered at $0$, and $\bar D(0, \rho)$ is its closure.  In $\bar D(0, \rho) \setminus \{0\}$ we have, from (1),

$f(z) = z^{-n}g(z); \tag{2}$

now writing $z = re^{i \theta}$ so that $z^n = r^n e^{i n \theta}$ in $\Delta$ and $z^{-n} = r^{-n}e^{-i n \theta}$ in $\Delta \setminus \{0\}$, we see from (2) that we may write

$f(z) = r^{-n}e^{-in \theta}g(z) \tag{3}$

in $\bar D(0, \rho) \setminus \{0\}$, whence

$\vert f(z) \vert^2 = f(z) \bar f(z) = r^{-2n} g(z) \bar g(z) = r^{-2n} \vert g(z) \vert^2 \tag{4}$

or

$\vert f(z) \vert = r^{-n} \vert g(z) \vert, \tag{5}$

also holding in $\bar D(0, \rho) \setminus \{0\}$; and since $\vert g(z) \vert > \gamma$ on $\bar D(0, \rho)$, we see that

$\vert f(z) \vert > \gamma r^{-n} \tag{6}$

in $\bar D(0, \rho) \setminus \{0\}$.

Having prepared the estimate (6) for $f(z)$ on $\bar D(0, \rho) \setminus \{0\}$, we may proceed to evaluate the integral

$\int_{\bar D(0, \rho) \setminus \{0\}} \vert f(z) \vert dx dy \tag{7}$

by the usual means:  *viz.*, we begin by picking real $\epsilon$ such that $0 < \epsilon < \rho$ and evaluate the integral over the annular region $A = \bar D(0, \rho) \setminus D(0, \epsilon)$; switching to polar coordinates, we have

$\int_A \vert f(z) \vert dx dy = \int_A \vert f(z) \vert r dr d\theta = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_\epsilon^\rho \vert f(z) \vert r dr d\theta > \gamma \int_0^{2\pi} \int_\epsilon^\rho r^{-n} r dr d\theta, \tag{8}$

where use has been made of (6).  Continuing in this direction,

$\gamma \int_0^{2\pi} \int_\epsilon^\rho r^{-n} r dr d\theta = 2 \pi \gamma \int_\epsilon^\rho r^{1 - n} dr; \tag{9}$

if $n = 2$, then we obtain

$\int_A \vert f(z) \vert dx dy > 2\pi \gamma \int_\epsilon^\rho r^{-1} dr = 2\pi \gamma (\ln r \mid_\epsilon^\rho = 2 \pi \gamma \ln(\dfrac{\rho}{\epsilon}), \tag{10}$

whereas if $n > 2$ we have

$\int_A \vert f(z) \vert dx dy > 2\pi \gamma \int_\epsilon^\rho r^{1 - n} dr = 2\pi \gamma (\dfrac{1}{2 - n} r^{2 - n}\mid_\epsilon^\rho$
$= 2 \pi \gamma \dfrac{1}{2 - n}(\rho^{2 - n} - \epsilon^{2 - n}); \tag{11}$

in either case we see that

$\int_A \vert f(z) \vert dx dy \to \infty \; \; \text{as} \;\; \epsilon \to 0. \tag{12}$

This shows that, with the conventional means of evaluation, $\int_{\bar D(0, \rho)} \vert f(z) \vert dx dy$ is unbounded, but since

$\int_\Delta \vert f(z) \vert dx dy \ge \int_{\bar D(0, \rho)} \vert f(z) \vert dx dy, \tag{13}$

$\int_\Delta \vert f(z) \vert dx dy$ is unbounded as well; thus

$\int_\Delta \vert f(z) \vert dx dy < \infty \tag{14}$

implies we must have $n < 2$; the pole of $f(z)$ at $0$ must be of order at most $1$.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***